# Слайдер jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Короче, есть такой блок

```
<div class="image" id="img"></div>
```

В него загружаются img с файла.

Суть в том как, например, при нажатии на .next перебирать img, все прятать, а один показывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#img').find('img').hide().eq(тут номер которого нужно показать).show();
```

Comment: ну а можно же как-то определять макс количество фото, или это нужно по другому тогда сделать ?